# Get the number of characters on a Button

Tags: android, android-button

Buttons in Android have number of attributes. Is there anyway to count the number of characters on the Button?

Comment: yeah, sure, look at the text property and count it (using string.size())

Answer (score 3):

have you tried

```
mButton.getText().length()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
btn.getText().toString().length();
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the  button name using getText() method.Then count that string(ButtonName) length using length() method.the complete code as like below

```
int charlength =button.getText().toString().length();
```

Comment: Can you just describe in 2 lines on how it would fix the issue?

Comment: please check that description is enough or not?